# Sharepoint REST 429 error. Multiple users read the same config file

Tags: sharepoint-rest-api

I am working on a JAVA onPrem app. For this app I have a config file which must be accessible by all the users that are using the app on startup. To achieve this I've tried using sharepoint. I've implemented the following :

- Created a new site in sharepoint.
- Created a new REST App for this site to which I've gave full permissions. (got clientId , clientSecret )
- In java I've created a connector for this app. (using tokens)
- Also I've implemented the REST requests to get/Post the config file.

Since the app should not have more than 100 user online at any time, I thought that this should be supported by sharepoint.

When I was testing the app from time to time I get the 429 Too many requests error (feature still in test, I was the only one making requests). When I read the header the retry after is set to 90 secs.
I've read this article  ([link](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/general-development/how-to-avoid-getting-throttled-or-blocked-in-sharepoint-online)) , but I still do not understand why what I described above is not allowed in sharepoint.
Is there something that I can do so that what I described above is possible in sharepoint ?
I've considered Sharepoint as an option because is the only place where all my user have access. It is not easy for me to find a "location" (Drive, Server, other) on which all my users have access.

Comment: Are you using SharePoint on-premises or SharePoint Online?

Comment: Sharepoint on-premises.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SharePoint throttles requests when the server is already too busy. It determines this using performance counters on the server.

[Request Throttling](https://docs.microsoft.com/previous-versions/office/developer/sharepoint-2010/ff407390(v=office.14))

It sounds like your application is making a lot of read requests to the configuration file. It's for this reason that configuration files are normally stored on either the server where the application is hosted or on the client's machine, if it is a desktop application.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! The application behavior changes based on what this config file contains. As an admin of the application I want to be able to update this config file and by having the config file in sharepoint all my users can read it at startup. I do not want to release a new version of the software for each config change.

Comment: It seems like you need to build a service for clients to call from your application, rather than user's requesting the entire configuration file every time. It doesn't sound like SharePoint is the correct solution for hosting other applications config files. It's primarily a document management system/CMS.